# Selection from numeric vector based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I am generating a dummy dataset using made up values and want to randomly assign values to certain rows based on conditions in R.

However, my script returns only one of the sample values per condition.

Ideally, I would want all sample values represented but randomly assigned to the rows based on conditions.

Below are two approaches I used, however, neither provides the random selection needed.

Coding attempt 1.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123) 

patient_data$strength <- NA

patient_data1 <- patient_data %>%
  mutate(
    strength = case_when(
      medication_name == "morphine" & frequency == "1-2" ~ as.character(sample(c(10, 30, 100, 200), 1, prob = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))),
      medication_name == "codeine" & frequency == "1-2" ~ as.character(sample(c(60, 90, 120), 1, prob = c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3))),
      medication_name == "oxycodone" & frequency == "1-2" ~ as.character(sample(c(20, 40, 80, 120), 1, prob = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))),
      medication_name == "oxycodone" & frequency == "4-6" ~ as.character(sample(c(5, 10, 20), 1, prob = c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3))),
      medication_name == "tramadol" & frequency == "4-6" ~ as.character((50)),
      medication_name == "tramadol" & frequency == "1-2" ~ as.character(sample(c(75, 150, 300, 400), 1, prob = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))),
      medication_name == "fentanyl" & frequency == "1-4" ~ as.character((200)),
      medication_name == "fentanyl" & frequency %in% c("1", "2") ~ as.character(sample(c(25, 50, 75, 100), 1, prob = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25))),
      medication_name == "buprenorphine" & frequency %in% c("1", "2") ~ as.character(sample(c(5, 10, 20), 1, prob = c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3))),
      medication_name %in% c("morphine", "codeine") & frequency == "4-6" ~ as.character(sample(c(15, 30), 1, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))),
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  )

print(patient_data1)
```

Coding attempt 2.

```
set.seed(123)

patient_data$strength <- NA

patient_data2 <- patient_data %>%
  mutate(
    strength = ifelse(medication_name == "morphine" & frequency == "1-2",
      sample(c(10, 30, 100, 200), size = 1),
      ifelse(medication_name == "morphine" & frequency == "4-6",
      sample(c(15, 30), size = 1),
      ifelse(medication_name == "codeine" & frequency == "1-2",
      sample(c(60, 90, 120), size = 1),
      ifelse(medication_name == "codeine" & frequency == "4-6",
      sample(c(15, 30), size = 1),
      ifelse(medication_name == "oxycodone" & frequency == "1-2",
      sample(c(20, 40, 80, 120), size = 1),
      ifelse(medication_name == "oxycodone" & frequency == "4-6",
      sample(c(5, 10, 20), size = 1),
      ifelse(medication_name == "tramadol" & frequency == "1-2",
      sample(c(75, 150, 300, 400), size = 1),
      ifelse(medication_name == "tramadol" & frequency == "4-6", 50,
      ifelse(medication_name == "fentanyl" & frequency == "1-4", 200,
      ifelse(medication_name == "fentanyl" & (frequency == "1" | frequency == "2"),
      sample(c(25, 50, 75, 100), size = 1),
      ifelse(medication_name == "buprenorphine" & (frequency == "1" | frequency == "2"),
      sample(c(5, 10, 20), size = 1), NA
      ))))
  )))))
)))

print(patient_data2)
```

These two scripts return the following limited output values.

Starting dataframe.

```
patient_data <- read.table(text="medication_name   frequency   strength
codeine            4-6          NA      
codeine            4-6          NA      
morphine           1-2          NA      
morphine           1-2          NA      
codeine            4-6          NA      
fentanyl           1-4          NA      
morphine           1-2          NA      
morphine           1-2          NA      
morphine           1-2          NA      
oxycodone          4-6          NA", header=T)
```

Current resultant dataset output.

```
medication_name.    frequency.    strength.
codeine             4-6           30        
codeine             4-6           30        
morphine            1-2           10        
morphine            1-2           10        
codeine             4-6           30        
fentanyl            1-4           200       
morphine            1-2           10        
morphine            1-2           10        
morphine            1-2           10        
oxycodone           4-6           20
```

Output selection 1 (distribution should reflect the entered sample values).

```
 patient_data1$strength  n    percent
                    100 78 0.46706587
                     15 37 0.22155689
                     20  3 0.01796407
                    200 12 0.07185629
                      5 24 0.14371257
                     50 13 0.07784431
```

Output selection 2 (distribution should reflect the entered sample values).

```
 patient_data2$strength  n    percent
                     10 81 0.48502994
                     20 24 0.14371257
                     25  5 0.02994012
                     30 37 0.22155689
                     50  8 0.04790419
                    200 12 0.07185629
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mutate()` function operates on entire columns of data at once, it does not operate per-row by default. So the easiest thing to do would be to generate all the random values at once by selecting `n()` random values rather than `1`. You also need to enable replacement for this to work. So you should be able to do

```
patient_data %>%
  mutate(
    strength = case_when(
      medication_name == "morphine" & frequency == "1-2" ~ as.character(sample(c(10, 30, 100, 200), n(), prob = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25), replace=TRUE)),
      medication_name == "codeine" & frequency == "1-2" ~ as.character(sample(c(60, 90, 120),  n(), prob = c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3), replace=TRUE)),
      medication_name == "oxycodone" & frequency == "1-2" ~ as.character(sample(c(20, 40, 80, 120),  n(), prob = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25), replace=TRUE)),
      medication_name == "oxycodone" & frequency == "4-6" ~ as.character(sample(c(5, 10, 20), n(), prob = c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3), replace=TRUE)),
      medication_name == "tramadol" & frequency == "4-6" ~ as.character((50)),
      medication_name == "tramadol" & frequency == "1-2" ~ as.character(sample(c(75, 150, 300, 400), n(), prob = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25), replace=TRUE)),
      medication_name == "fentanyl" & frequency == "1-4" ~ as.character((200)),
      medication_name == "fentanyl" & frequency %in% c("1", "2") ~ as.character(sample(c(25, 50, 75, 100), n(), prob = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25), replace=TRUE)),
      medication_name == "buprenorphine" & frequency %in% c("1", "2") ~ as.character(sample(c(5, 10, 20), n(), prob = c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3), replace=TRUE)),
      medication_name %in% c("morphine", "codeine") & frequency == "4-6" ~ as.character(sample(c(15, 30), n(), prob = c(0.5, 0.5), replace=TRUE)),
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  )
```

You could also add `rowwise() %>%`  before you do your `mutate()` in the original `case_when` code but it's generally better (faster) to use vectorized operations.

Comment: Many thanks... does the trick MrFlick.

Comment: Hi again.  It appears that code drops the tramadol sample values of 150, 300, 400.  I have increased the total row count to check, however, the values still do not show.  I have changed to use the rowwise() suggestion and no change.  It is curious how only these three values are dropped whilst the rest show in the output.

Comment: It's unclear what could be going wrong. Are you saying all values are 75? How many sample are in your data? It would be easier to help if you had a reproducible example that could be used for testing.

Comment: After checking for snagging issues, I noticed that your rowwise() suggestion was also needed in an earlier line of code... I now have the output sought after... many thanks for the assistance.